# JavaScript - disable internet connectivity

Tags: javascript, angularjs, offline

I want to test my website for offline uses, is there a way to disable website connectivity on `bootstrap`, before anything loads, so all data will be loaded from `cache`.

There are many [offline](https://github.com/hubspot/offline) libs, but I didn't find a way to disable connectivity programmatically.

Angularjs solutions will be great as well.

Comment: you can't do it in javascript - but you can quickly set the browser to "Work Offline"

Comment: I will try that, thanks.

Comment: You can set up a $http interceptor to reject all requests with -1 status and delay. This may be beneficial for integration/e2e testing. But yes, doing this in dev tools is more straightforward

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a way, in Google Chrome, under Developer console (<kbd>Ctrl-Shift-I</kbd>), Network tab.

[image]

Comment: Can't find it.  They probably removed the option...